# drupal_goto not working in hook user login

Tags: users

I have $u variable which stores the path in hook user login to redirect users to the page.

```
drupal_goto($u);
```

I am not being redirected to the page- path $u.
drupal_goto not working.
I have tried everything increased te weight of the module,even tried with $_GET['destination'].

Comment: Cleared the Cache? I guess you have written the hook function name correctly. Did you try a fixed URL? like 'user/edit'?

Comment: Please share your code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using drupal_goto(), try passing the path in **$edit['redirect']** in [hook_user_login](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7) as below:

```
<?php
/** 
 * Implements hook_user_login().
 */
function hook_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  // To check if the form is not the user reset form.
  if (!isset($_POST['form_id']) || $_POST['form_id'] != 'user_pass_reset') {
    $GLOBALS['destination'] = 'PATH_YOU_WANT_TO_REDIRECT';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Tried with $edit['redirect'] also. did not work.

Comment: @neetumorwani can you once try this: `$GLOBALS['destination'] = 'PATH_YOU_WANT_TO_REDIRECT';`. Don't forget to clear the cache after appplying the changes